# Remove newlines from certain areas not all | Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, newline, keyword

How do I remove the newline ('\n') using notepad++ only in certain returning areas.

E.g.

```
Keyword1 "this is the text that I want to 
         take the new lines out of. But not
         the area around it"
Keyword2
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Keyword1 "this is te text that I want to take the new lines out of. But not the area around it"
Keyword2
```

I only want to take the newlines out of these areas (there are multiple in the .txt file) and not out of the whole file.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work out how the two cases are distinguished? What characters are always before or after the newlines to be kept as compared to the newlines to be deleted.

In your short example, it appears as if newlines to be removed are followed by several spaces (or tabs) whereas newlines to be kept are not.

So you can do a replace of `\r\n[\t ]{3,}` with , make sure that "regular expression" is selected. This will replace any newline followed by three or more tabs and spaces with a single space.

You may need to alter the `\r\n` part depending on the line endings in the file. Try using menu => **View** => **Show symbol** => **Show end of line** to see the line endings in your file.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `\R\h+`
Replace with: `a space`

Where `\R` stands for any kind of linebreak and `\h` any kind of horizontal space.